# Angular 2 google map marker click event triggers div appearance in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript

So I have an angular 2 application that's supposed to have a map, a sidebar, and a navbar. The map is supposed to be taking all the window beside the sidebar and under the navbar. The angular structure is as follows:

1. a main-window component containg the templates for the navbar, sidebar, map, and a div that should pop up and take the right part of the screen when I click a marker on the map. I am having all of them in one component for each section to easily access the variables in the other parts. The div I want to pop on the right when I click on the marker is not the popup-window existing in the maps API; It's a div I hardcoded into the component's template and I am hiding it or showing it based on a flag in the component (I had to make this clear).
2. A main-window.html template that comprises the navbar div, the sidebar div, the map div with an `id="google-map`, and the highlights-section div with ngIf hiding it as long as the `this.highlightsSection` flag in the component is set to false

This is the code that's supposed to be achieving this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Sensor } from '../entities/sensor';

declare const google: any;

@Component({
   selector: 'app-main-window',
   templateUrl: './main-window.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./main-window.component.css']
})
export class MainWindowComponent implements OnInit {

highlightsSection: boolean = false;

zoom: number = 14;
lat: number = 26.67946;
lng: number = -80.41719;
map: any;
marker: any;
mapProp: any = {
    center:   new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lng),
    zoom: this.zoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};


constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.map =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-map"), this.mapProp);
}

toggleHighlights(): void {
    if(!this.highlightsSection) {
        this.highlightsSection = true;
    } else {
        this.highlightsSection = false;
    }
}

registerMarkers(): void {
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
        title: "Hello world!"
    });
    this.marker.setMap(this.map);
    this.marker.addListener('click', function() {
        // What should go here to allow the marker to change the flag   value of highlightsSection variable??
   }); 
}    
}
```

You see those two handler functions: `this.toggleHighlights()` and `this.registerMarkers()`
I need to use them as follows I need to have a button in side bar to trigger the `this.registerMarkers()` one to show the markers (Until this point it works well) and inside this `this.registerMarkers()` after showing the marker I need to add event listener on marker click to trigger the other `toggleHighlights()` function which in turn shows this rights section of highlights div on the right of the map.

The problem is that it seems the `marker.addEventListener()` can't trigger the `this.toggleHighlights()` on the click and I can't understand why

I am new to both angular2 and typescript and the only way I have done something like that before was by using jquery and the DOM but I need to have the concept of component to store multiple flags and variables and I can't achieve this

PS: I have tried the agm third party component by sebastian and it's very limited in functionality so I can't rely on it

I would be glad if someone helped me on figuring out what's happening here

Comment: I'd love to have a stackblitz or plunker for this. Or if it's a public project that you can share, I'd love to clone and take a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try using a closure; like below:

```
registerMarkers(): void {
    var toggler = () => {
        // toggle the flag here
    }

    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng},
        title: "Hello world!"
    });
    this.marker.setMap(this.map);
    this.marker.addListener('click', function() {
        toggler();
   }); 
}
```

Personally, I do not highly like/recommend this solution, but I think, this workaround would work (at last until you find some other solution). I too had faced a similar condition when I used the same because I did not find any other solution.

Also, note that I have not run this code before posting, but just to give you the hint.

So, please try before down-voting... :)   and hit answer, if this works for you... :)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and tell you. But I really don't understand why is it that hard to access the component variables from click handler. It is much easier I guess with angular 1 and the controller's $scope and $rootScope!

Comment: How I came to understand it is the difference between Scopes and Prototypes. While all the variables and functions we normally create go in a scope (global and local), the class properties in TS actually go into the Prototype of an Object which can only be access through the object reference. Hence, 'this' matters!!!